# whats wrong with def_list_of_dups(some_list):

Tags: python

Why is my some_list not defined ????

I'm trying to find the duplicates in my_list and then print out everything without duplicates

```
def list_of_dups(some_list):
    new_list=[]
    some_list=[]
    some_list+=my_list
    for i in some_list:
        if i in new_list:
            print "hi"
        else:
            new_list+=remember[i]
    return new_list

dups = list_of_dups(some_list)
print dups
```

Comment: where is `remember` initialized ? also, please fix your indentation. This code wont even run properly.

Comment: oh sorry remember should be some_list

Comment: And where is `my_list` initialised? And why are you accepting an argument, only to immediately shadow it locally with an empty list again in `some_list=[]`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your strange

```
new_list+=remember[i]
```

should instead just be

```
new_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may give you the desired output depending on how you want to remove duplicate elements:

```
def remove_dups(input_list):
    output = []
    for element in input_list:
        if element in output: 
            print 'Duplicate Found: ' + str(element)
        else:
            output.append(element)
    return output


test_list1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
test_list2 = ['a', 'a', '2', 2, 'dsd']
print remove_dups(test_list1)
print remove_dups(test_list2)

# OUTPUT
# Duplicate Found: 1
# Duplicate Found: 5
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# Duplicate Found: a
# ['a', '2', 2, 'dsd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're just trying to accomplish your end goal, you can use Python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to turn your list into a list without duplicates:

```
for e in set(some_list):
    print e
```

This won't maintain the ordering of `some_list`, though.

If, on the other hand, you're trying to implement your own function as an exercise…well, using `set` may not be what you want. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_of_dups(some_list):  ##some_list is passed from below
       new_list=[]
       some_list=[]           ##some_list is cleared
       some_list+=my_list     ##where is my_list coming from?
       for i in some_list:     ###here some_list
            if i in new_list:
               print "hi"
           else:
               new_list+=remember[i]
       return new_list
dups = list_of_dups(some_list)

print dups
```

this shoule be

```
def list_of_dups(my_list):  ##my_list is passed from below
       new_list=[]
       some_list=[]           ##some_list is cleared
       some_list+=my_list
       for i in some_list:     ###here some_list
            if i in new_list:
               print "hi"
           else:
               new_list+=remember[i]
       return new_list
dups = list_of_dups(my_list)

print dups
```

Comment: To clarify - *some_list is cleared* - no - it's not cleared... the assignment merely introduces a new function local name that binds to an empty list